# How to pass-through multiple USB devices with the same Vendor- and Device-ID in QEMu/Libvirt?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, passthrough

I have three identical USB devices on my VM host that I would like to pass-through to a VM:
[image]

I can pass-through only one device as they all have the same vendor- and device-ID, the element in the VM libvirt XML file look like this:

```
...
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
    <source>
        <vendor id='0x064f'/>
        <product id='0x03e9'/>
    </source>
    <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
</hostdev>
...
```

Any tricks?

Perhaps one way could be if it was possible to change the device-id of a device?

Answer (score 0):

It seem you can do it in the native qemu cmd using either `-device usb-host,hostbus=bus,hostaddr=addr` or `-device usb-host,hostbus=bus,hostport=port`
(sources: [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452934/can-i-pass-through-a-usb-port-via-qemu-command-line), [linux-kvm.org](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest))

And to specify native qemu cmd parameters in libvirt xml you use something like this

```
 ..
 </devices>
 <qemu:commandline>
    xxxx
 </qemu:commandline>
 ..
```

(*I update the finals details when/if I succeed, but this is just to get started*)